# Which javascript/node module is best for Elastic search Query DSL

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi started using elasticsearch in my node app, from the elasticsearch document,

> elastic.js, esq, or bodybuilder can be used to make building query
>   bodies easier.

I am not sure which is the best module to use, both modules have not been updated since a while.Bodybuilder does not support all the filters/queries, elastic.js looks like it supports most of the filters/queries, but its documentation is inaccessible. Can somebody suggest me a good module.

Comment: How about the [official JS client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/index.html) library?

Comment: @Val do you mean elasticsearch.js, I dont think it has the functionality to construct the queries

Comment: for those who have -ve, it's a shame on you, you are suppose to answer if you know, marking -ve does not solve a problem.

Comment: For what it's worth, I haven't downvoted but since it's certainly going to be closed, I prefer to simply comment than provide an illegitimate answer ;-) Anyhow, if you're focused on the DSL part, you might also try [esql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esql)

Comment: [elastic-builder](https://github.com/sudo-suhas/elastic-builder), heavily inspired by elastic.js, full support for 5.x DSL. Disclosure - I authored the module. [Feedback](https://github.com/sudo-suhas/elastic-builder/issues) welcome

Answer (score 1):

The official js library is the best, I would say.

For the query, I create my own, concatenating values.

This is the most complete example for using it: [Link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/quick-start.html#_more_complex_filtered_query).
That and do previous to that one in the same page.

Comment: I am using the official js library, elasticsearch.js. I was only looking for query part. The three modules specified in elastic doc, none of them implement all the filters or aggregations. I think creating my own query would be the way to go.